# Updating rotary knob in real time with SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, slider, avaudiorecorder, avaudioengine

I'm currently trying to convert a slider in to a rotary knob and having a tough time of it all. The knob works in design but i'm struggling to set the correct value within the knob and as a result change the value within the app in real time.

I'm using AVAudio to set up an engine for people to record with that has effects like Reverb and Delay.

The reverb value is set as followed within the Audio Class:

```
@Published var reverbValue: Float = 0.0
```

and later on referenced in a function to change it's value

```
   func changeReverbValue() {
    
    setReverb.wetDryMix = reverbValue
    

}
```

When I use a regular slider as follows the change works:

```
Slider(value: $recordingsettings.reverbValue, in: Float(0.0)...recordingsettings.reverbMaxValue, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                
   self.recordingsettings.changeReverbValue()

  }).accentColor(Color.white)
```

As mentioned the knob works fine in its design:

```
    ZStack {
        
        Knobs(color: .orange)
            .rotationEffect(
                .degrees(max(0, initialCircleState()))
            )
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onEnded({ _ in
                startDragValue = -1.0
            })
            .onChanged { dragValue in
                let touchDifferential =  touchDifference(dragValue)
               
                setInitialDragVal()
                
                let computedTouch = computeTouch(touchDifferential)
                
                print(computedTouch)
                
                baseValue = getBaseVal(computedTouch)
                
                let normalizeVal = baseValue / touchAmt
                
                value = Float(normalizeVal * rngOffset(range: bounds) + bounds.lowerBound)
                print("vaule is: \(value)")

            }
            )
            
        GrayCircle(bounds: bounds)
        OrangeCircle(baseValue: $value, bounds: bounds)
        
    }
    .rotationEffect(bounds.lowerBound < 0 ? .degrees(90) : .degrees(107))
```

I've had some success connecting the knob to the reverb value to the point where the slider also moves when the rotary knob does, however the changeReverbValue function doesn't work.

The success comes from setting the value within the knob view as follows:

```
@Binding var value: AUValue
```

And then referencing the knob on the same struct of the main view as the slider:

```
Knob(value: $recordingsettings.reverbValue, bounds: 0...CGFloat(recordingsettings.reverbMaxValue))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.recordingsettings.changeReverbValue()
                        }
```

The on tap gesture was a way in which I thought it might call the change reverb value function when the knob was turned but to no avail.

The binding value passed in the knob also has other challenges. For some reason when I playback audio without headphones and then turn the knob the audio starts to stutter. This doesn't happen with headphones and I find that pretty weird.

Anyone know how I could reference the reverb value within the rotary knob and have the changeReverbValue function called at the same time?

I just want to replace the slider with something that looks better. Otherwise i'm going to have to leave this for a bit and just implement the sliders instead throughout the app.

If I don't set the value of the knob as @binding in the rotary knob view the track doesn't stutter on playback but then I don't know if it's possible to change the reverb value without a @binding var.

Comment: why not put "self.recordingsettings.changeReverbValue()" in the Knob ".onChanged { ... }"?

Comment: @workingdog I did try that but it didn't work. Should of clarified within my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to parse a precise singular problem statement from the narrative, so this is perhaps just an off-base commentary and not a solution. I walked away thinking your problem is: a custom UI component is "jumpy/stuttery" during interaction and produces similarly punctate effects on app state.

If that's fair, I worked around the same issue in my first SwiftUI app. The cause could be two things:

1. Not using the right async queue by accident.
2. Forcing an `@State` or `@Published` property to update for all global state changes. That means you are pushing stale state from earlier back into an interaction, possibly with a circular feedback loop.

The solution is pretty simple. Request and consume model updates with both a value **and** a source tag. Throttle and filter out the self-tag to keep local state responsive to only one just-in-time data stream.

I used that pattern in that first app (free, `Inclusivity` for Mac) to coordinate an HSV color wheel and color channel custom slider components. The wheel, sliders, and other interactions feed/read a shared Combine pipeline (`CurrentValueSubject<SourcedColorVector,Never>`.erasedToAny()).

Some sample gestures, which simply punt the gating work to a view model:

#### The HSVWheel drag-around or click gesture

```swift
    private func touchUpInWheel() -> ExclusiveGesture<_ChangedGesture<DragGesture>, _EndedGesture<DragGesture>> {
        ExclusiveGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .named(wheel))
                .onChanged { change in
                    let adjusted = CGPoint(x: change.translation.width - targetDiameter + change.startLocation.x / 2,
                                           y: change.translation.height - targetDiameter + change.startLocation.y / 2)
                        vm.setHueSat(drag: adjusted)
                },
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .named(wheel))
                .onEnded { end in
                    let click = CGPoint(x: end.location.x - vm.radius,
                                        y: end.location.y - vm.radius)
                        vm.setHueSat(click: click)
                }
        )
        
    }
```

#### A typical slider gesture (this is the vertical value slider)

```swift
private func tapAndDrag() -> _EndedGesture<_ChangedGesture<DragGesture>>  {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0,
                    coordinateSpace: .named(valuePickerSpace))
            .onChanged { value in
                let location = value.location.y - .valueSliderGestureOffset
                vm.setValueKnobLocation(raw: location)
            }
            .onEnded { end in
                let location = end.location.y - .valueSliderGestureOffset
                vm.setValueKnobLocation(raw: location)
            }
    }
```